Trouble Obtaining JWT Token from Keycloak Realm with NextAuth in Next.js and Quarkus Backend
I am a student and I've been grappling with integrating Next.js, Keycloak, and Quarkus in my web application stack. Specifically, I've successfully set up NextAuth to connect to my Keycloak realm for user authentication in my Next.js frontend. Moreover, I've configured my Quarkus backend to authenticate against the same Keycloak realm, and I've marked certain endpoints with @Authenticated to ensure secure access.
However, I'm encountering a hurdle: while login/logout functionalities work seamlessly with NextAuth and Keycloak, I'm not receiving a JWT token upon user login through NextAuth. This missing token prevents me from forwarding user authentication information to my Quarkus backend.
Here's a brief overview of my setup:
Next.js Frontend: Utilizing NextAuth to connect to Keycloak realm for user authentication.
Quarkus Backend: Configured to authenticate against the same Keycloak realm, with certain endpoints requiring authentication via @Authenticated annotation.

Here's the crux of the issue: despite successful login/logout flows, I'm not receiving a JWT token from Keycloak via NextAuth. Consequently, I'm unable to pass this token to my backend, hindering further interactions.
I've reviewed my configuration settings and ensured that:
NextAuth is correctly configured with Keycloak credentials.
Quarkus backend is set up to validate JWT tokens from Keycloak.
Keycloak realm settings permit token issuance for NextAuth.

Despite these efforts, I'm still unable to obtain the JWT token. I suspect there might be a missing configuration or a misunderstanding in how NextAuth handles tokens from Keycloak.
Questions:

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with NextAuth and Keycloak integration?
Is it common or feasible to use NextAuth with Keycloak for frontend authentication and then  pass the obtained token to a separate backend, like Quarkus?
Are there any specific configurations or additional steps I should consider to ensure seamless token retrieval and transmission between NextAuth and my Quarkus backend?

Any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Quarkus can not affect the way the NextAuth and Keycloak integration is done, but indeed, as long as NextAuth passes the token to Quarkus as a bearer access token, as Authorization: Bearer token, it will verify it. As far as NextAuth is concerned, please check in NextAuth forums too how to have it use authorization code flow with OIDC providers to acquire tokens

Can you post the NextAuthJS (AuthJS) configuration? I mean, the auth.js file with the callbacks and so on?
